# How to add values in a list successively using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to add values in a list successively.
is there any way to do it by using list comprehension?

```
input_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
expected_list = [1,3,6,10,15,21]
```

this can be done by this function

```
def add_list(input_list):
    required_list =[input_list[0]]
    for item in range(1,len(input_list)):
        required_list.append(required_list[-1] + input_list[item])
    return (required_list)
```

Comment: What's your input list?What's your expect output?

Comment: @FrankAK input_list = [1,2,3,4,5] expected_list = [1,3,6,10,15]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function. This function is available in the `itertools` module for Python 3.2 and greater.  If you are using python < 3.2 you can write your own function like this.

```
# myscript.py
import operator


def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    """
    Return an iterator whose items are the accumulated results of a function
    (specified by the optional *func* argument) that takes two arguments.
    By default, returns accumulated sums with :func:`operator.add`.
    """
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    else:
        yield total

    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

**DEMO**

*1) Python version < 3.2(Use your own function)*

```
>> from myscript import accumulate
>> print list(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])) # Running sum
>> [1,3,6,10,15,21]
```

*Using List comprehension.*

```
>> from myscript import accumulate
>> out_ = [item for item in accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])] 
>> out_
>> [1,3,6,10,15,21]
```

2) *Python version > 3.2(The function is already in the `itertools` module, Just use it :))*

```
 >> from itertools import accumulate
 >> print(list(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])))
```

*Using List comprehension.*

```
 >> from itertools import accumulate
 >> out_ = [item for item in accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])] 
 >> out_
 >> [1,3,6,10,15,21]
```

**NOTE**

If you want to find the accumulated product/division/etc you can pass the corresponding `func` parameter to the `accumulate` function.

```
>> import operator
>> out_ = [item for item in accumulate([1, 2, 3], func=operator.mul)] # accumulated product.
>> out_
>> [1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: how `operator.mul` return that result when you passed `[1,2,3]` as input @ABDULNIYASPM

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) along with list comprehension to achieve your results.

```
>>> from functools import reduce

>>> items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l[:b]) for b in range(1,len(l)+1)]
>>> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import itertools
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
required_list = [bi for bi in itertools.accumulate(original_list)]
print(required_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using list comprehension and without importing any module, you can do it using the below code:

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
required_list = [sum(original_list[:val]) for val in range(1,len(original_list)+1)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

You can comment below, if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by making use of `enumarate()`

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [sum(a[:i[0]+1]) for i in enumerate(a)]
print b
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

Adding this answer for just another solution for this question